# No interference in double-slit experiment when slits are very close?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

In the video down below Stephen Wolfram says that we see the interference in the double-slit experiment because the slits are too far away from each other. I suppose it means there should be no interference if the slits are extremely close. Have anyone tried putting the slits extremely close (maybe a few atoms apart)?

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=maLc4ClUNzQ&t=2890s

Comment: Any object in the path of a single (or many photons) will cause the photon to diffract (i.e. alter its course) in a probabilistic manner. Furthermore photons in a DSE which typically use more coherent light are always subject to the EM field and the boundaries (source, slit, screen) ... which result in photon paths that are preferred.  In the DSE there are no photons in the dark spots, all are in the light.  For a very very small divider the pattern would be very weak to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't offhand know of a two slit example, but for multiple slits there are gratings made for x-ray spectroscopy. The [Chandra HETG gratings](https://space.mit.edu/HETG/instrument_description.html) have spacings less than an optical wavelength. They therefore don't disperse optical light (although they polarize it).

Comment: Maybe you can explain why it would not work for optical wavelengths.